# Does Android ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS allow background service?

Tags: android, android-service

I've been testing battery optimization whitelist with background service.

A background service destroyed after few minutes(in my device about 1m) when app is background.

But the service started by app whitelisted on battery optimization seems not to be destroyed even if it's not foreground service.

IMHO, battery optimization allow apps to be excluded from doze mode and app standby mode not background service restriction.

Does battery optimization whitelist allow background service too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the customize OS of xiaomi, one plus etc. This behavior is highly rely on their OS customization.

Battery optimization will definitely helps up to some extent to run alarm receiver and background services. But in my experience with One Plus 5T device, user has to manually change battery optimization this from setting. If we implement this by using following code, and even after user Allow to run service in background in popup, this doesn't make any change. User  compulsory has to go in setting to mark particular app as not battery optimized.

```
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + this.getPackageName()));
                this.startActivityForResult(intent, IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS_REQUEST);
```

Here just want to let you know, few of the use cases mentioned on the developer site, that can only acceptable to make your app white listed:

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#whitelisting-cases

Also as per the google play policy,

> Google Play policies prohibit apps from requesting direct exemption
>   from Power Management features in Android 6.0+ (Doze and App Standby)
>   unless the core function of the app is adversely affected

Comment: Thanks, Google Play policies are not matter because my app is just for test to battery optimization whitelist.

So, apps in whitelist can run background service and it is intended behavior although to add apps in whitelist is depends on OS. right?

Comment: Absolutely right. while app is on white list, it can launch services without limitation, and its background services are permitted to run. More you will find it this document also: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Comment: The intent seems not to work on latest Xiaomi devices